# Probability of getting 1 on a dice

Tags: probability

I want to ask that the probability of getting 1 on a dice is 1/6. But does this mean that if i roll a dice 6 times under same conditions, i will get 1 inevitably one time? If not then wouldn't it contradict the probability of 1/6?

Comment: The probability that you get no $1$ if you roll the die six times is $\left( \frac 56\right)^6$ so the probability that you get at least one $1$ is $1-\left( \frac 56\right)^6$  which is strictly less than $1$.

Comment: No, but you could interpret it this way: "The more the number of times I roll the dice, the closer the fraction of times I get '1' gets to $\dfrac{1}{6}$". See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But does this mean that if i roll a dice 6 times under same conditions, i will get 1 inevitably one time?

Certainly not! If you're unsure, roll a die and check. As lulu pointed out in the comments, if you roll a die 6 times, there is about a 33% chance that you won't see a one at all.

So, the unspoken part of your question is: what does the $1/6$ actually mean? The answer is: if you rolled the die *many, many* times (say, a thousand times or more), then you would get *around* $1/6$ of the die rolls to be a one. Not exactly $1/6$, of course, but something quite close to that. And moreover, the more you roll the die, the closer to $1/6$ the observed proportion of ones will be.

Another interpretation of the $1/6$: if you rolled $6$ dice, then the *expected number* (i.e. average number) of ones shown on the dice will be $1$. So, what does "average" mean here? It means that if there were 10,000 parallel universes, and in each one a copy of you rolls $6$ dice, then different copies of you would see different numbers of ones on the dice. In one universe, you might see $0$ of the $6$ dice land on one; in another you might see $3$ of the $6$ dice land on one, and maybe in a very lucky universe you might get all $6$ dice to land on one. If you talk to each of the 10,000 copies of yourself, ask how many ones they saw, and take an average of those numbers, you'd get something close to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of 1's you get in total after rolling a perfect dice $n$ times is governed by  [the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Bernoulli_distribution). If $p$ is the probability of something happening and you do it $n$ times then the probability of it happening k times is given by:$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ The expectation $\mu$ is $np=n/6$ and the variance $\sigma^2$ is $np(1-p)=5n/36$.

For large $n$ this distribution is approximated by the normal distribution with corresponding mean and variance. So we can say that 95% of the time we will see the number of 1's lying within 2 standard deviations of the mean so in the interval $[\mu-2\sigma,\mu+2\sigma]=[n/6-2\times\sqrt{5n/36},n/6+2\times\sqrt{5n/36}]$.

For example if you roll the dice 6000 times the number of 1's seen will deviate from 1000, the expected value by greater than 60 only 5% of the time.